# Does anyone know where to find the Sefer toras Avraham by Reb avraham grodzenski?

Tags: jewish-books, mussar-ethics

If anyone knows where this Sefer,and other slabodka mussar seforim can be found. Or if anyone has them and is interested in selling them please call 929-842-8008 and leave a voicemail

Comment: I feel like this was maybe asked in the past. It's out of print. Someone would be doing a big chessed reprint it.

Comment: I have heard a rumor that it is in the process of being redone.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dovid and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

They just put it out in [Zundel Berman](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8).

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Dovid!

If you have access to Otzar HaChochma, it can be found [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/103789/p/1/t/1670122892800/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c)

If not and you are near any of the libraries listed [here via the links for Sefer Torat Avraham : maʼamarim ṿe-śiḥot mi-kitve-yado by Avraham Grodzinsḳi](http://worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n88137065/), that might be an idea.

*If you are specifically looking to own a copy then have your tried Biegeleisen or other sellers of used seforim?*